# Tweetstream not connecting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm using a recent version of Tweetstream and can't seem to connect to the twitter streaming API. I'm authenticating through oAuth like so:

```
require "rubygems"
require "tweetstream"

def index

  TweetStream.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = 'aaa'
    config.consumer_secret = 'aaa'
    config.oauth_token = '11329872-aaa'
    config.oauth_token_secret = 'aaa'
    config.auth_method = :oauth
    config.parser = :yajl
  end

  TweetStream::Client.new.track('words') do |status|
    puts "streaming"
    puts "#{status.text}"
  end
end
```

It eventually times out though with the following:

> TweetStream::ReconnectError (Failed to reconnect after 7 tries.)

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to this one was a missing required gem. All I needed to add was:

```
require 'yajl'
```

I also noticed that this is only required if you're using oAuth to authenticate with twitter.